# Sample for .NET Web API, .NET Identity, external login, and token authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api2, access-token, asp.net-identity-2

Where can I find a complete code sample (the entire project) that includes the following:

- .NET Web Api 2
- .NET Identity 2.0
- External login provider
- Token authentication instead of cookies

I have a Web API project working with an external login provider but it uses cookie authentication and does not use .NET Identity. I can't find any complete code examples that include the above four requirements.

Comment: Does this not have what you need? http://www.asp.net/aspnet/samples/aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 0):

The best working example one can find is the series of Mr.Mittal at Codeproject in it one can find Entity Framework, Generic Repository pattern and Unit of Work. 
Also all the stuff you explained 
.NET Web API 2
.NET Identity 2.0
External login provider
Token authentication instead of cookies
keep up with him you'll get to know how this all works here is the link [Enterprise Level Application Architecture with Web APIs using Entity Framework, Generic Repository Pattern and Unit of Work](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990492/RESTful-Day-sharp-Enterprise-Level-Application)